# GridLayout items will go out of bounds of device screen on real devices (not emulators) in android

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am trying to create a layout like this using `GridLayout` and I am seeing my result both on design screen in android studio and in android emulators but not on real devices (Samsung Galaxy s6 edge and Galaxy tab a 2016 tested).
Here's what I want:

[image]

And here is what I am getting on real devices:

[image]

as you can see the `EditText` on the right side is outside the device screen where as it has lots of margin to the right of the screen in the design screen(and on emulators)

here's my layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="sign up"
        android:id="@+id/textView_sign_up_header"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="#FFF"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:rowCount="5"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:useDefaultMargins="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editText_first_name"
                    android:hint="name"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:textDirection="rtl"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/global_text_size"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editText_last_name"
                    android:hint="family"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:textDirection="rtl"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/global_text_size"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

omitting `android:fillViewport="true"` from the `ScrollView` solved the problem